# Проблема при подключении

Tags: java, asterisk

Я хочу подключится к серверу астериска, но у меня выводит ошибку

```
Failed to execute goal on project mavenproject1: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.asteriskjava:mavenproject1:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.asteriskjava:asterisk-java:jar:1.0.0-final (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.asteriskjava:asterisk-java:jar:1.0.0-final: Could not transfer artifact org.asteriskjava:asterisk-java:pom:1.0.0-final from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/asteriskjava/asterisk-java/1.0.0-final/asterisk-java-1.0.0-final.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

Хотя я добавил зависимость

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.asteriskjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.asteriskjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>asterisk-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-final</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Сейчас актуальная версия asterisk-java 2.0.4: https://github.com/asterisk-java/asterisk-java . Попробуйте ее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что с 15 января 2020, The Central Maven Repository (https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334-Central-501-HTTPS-Required) перестал работать через http, и теперь работает только через https.
Вот ссылка на ответ с английского SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59764749/requests-to-http-repo1-maven-org-maven2-return-a-501-https-required-status-an